# Diffeomorphism between vector bundles

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I have some difficulty solving the following problem:

Let $M$ be a diffentiable manifold of dimension $m$, which admits a global base of differentiable vector fields $\{X_1,\ldots,X_m\}$; this $\{X_1(x),\ldots,X_m(x)\}$ is a basis of $T_xM$. Consider the map $\Psi:M\times\mathcal{R}^m\rightarrow TM$ given by

$\Psi(x,(v^1,\ldots,v^m))=\sum_{i=1}^mv^iX_i(x)$ for $x\in M$ and $v=(v^1,\ldots,v^m)\in\mathcal{R}^m$.

Show that $\Psi$ is a diffeomorphism.

So, it is clear that $\Psi$ is differenciable, since it is just a some of differenciable functions. But how can I calculate the inverse? I don't even know how to define the identity in $TM$.

I have heard that there is some theoreme, that guarantees the existence of a differenciable inverse for a bijective map between vector bundles, but I do not remember the exact theoreme nor if it applicable to this problem.

I am quite new to this topic and appreciate any help.

Greetings,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here's the strategy without taking the trouble of writing down the inverse. First show that your map is injective. Then show that it is a local diffeomorphism by proving that differential $d\Psi: T(M\times\mathbb{R}^m)\to T(TM)$ is an isomorphism everywhere.

Comment: To show that it is injective I use that if $(x,v)\neq(y,w)$ than $\psi(x,v)\neq\psi(y,w)$. This is clear since we have $\psi(x,v)-\psi(x,w)=\sum(v-w)^iX_i(x)\neq0$. But how can I show that the differential is an isomorphism?